# How to stop and resume a running program when condition is true

Tags: c#

I am running  sending SMS program using C# from 6.00 AM to 6.00 PM. I want to stop that process when it is 6PM and restart the process when it is 7AM on the following day. The following code is not working. When the program is running it does not stop when the time is 6PM. Plz help me to solve this. Thank you

```
new Thread(delegate()
{ 
    while (DateTime`me.Now.Hour.ToString("HH") != "18")
    {   
       sms.endSMS();
       Thread.Sleep(20000);}    
       Thread.Sleep(500000);
}).Start();
```

Comment: ...or, kill the process at 6PM each night then use Windows' built-in Task Scheduler to start your app at 7AM every day..

Comment: What's   DateTime`me?

Comment: Take a look also at Quartz.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend Using Windows Task Scheduler and Timers for this operation. However, if you want an answer for your specified code, you can use the below code.

```
Thread timerThread = new Thread(()=>
           {
               while(true)
               {
                   if(DateTime.Now.Hour >= 6 && DateTime.Now.Hour <= 17)
                   {
                       sms.SendSms();
                       Thread.Sleep(300000);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       Thread.Sleep(3600000);
                   }
               }});
        timerThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
        timerThread.IsBackground = true;
        timerThread.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a task scheduler like [Windows Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) or [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to start and stop the process at scheduled times of the day